# Installing two apk using one apk

Tags: java, android, apk

I googled a lot for how to install two apk using one apk, 
and every one told this is not possible.

But my requirement is to install two apk. I can give you example of google play.
Apk with name "Screen off" is actually one apk but when you install it, you will get
two apk installed in your mobile named
1. Screen off and 
2.Screen off and Lock.

Now, please tell me how they have done this.

Comment: The best you can do is to make an APK that once opened will download and install another apk. You can't install two APKs at one time

Comment: ...you know, I've come across programs before that secretly install additional programs without my knowledge or consent. Generally, I call these **viruses**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a second APK. They used a different activity of the same application. Inside the manifest you can change your activity section to this for both activities.

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```